# Dispatching event manually do not change event target value

Tags: javascript

Based on provided code, when the select option is changed, everything works fine and `event.target.value` contains an option value. But when the `change` event is triggered manually, for example on the form `reset` event, the value inside `event.target` object is changed, but `event.target.value` keeps an old value. For example:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <select name="number">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
    const element = document.querySelector('select')

    element.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
        console.log(event)
        console.log('Make Axios request with parameter: ' + event.target.value)
    })

    element.form.addEventListener('reset', function (event) {
        console.log('Form reset!')
        element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
    })
```

When the select option is changed to 1, output will be:

1. Event (where `target.value` is set to 1)
2. Make Axios request with parameter: 1

When the "Reset" button is clicked, output will be:

1. Form reset!
2. Event (where `target.value` is set to 0)
3. Make Axios request with paramter: 1

Does anyone knows why Event object is changed as it "should", but `event.target.value` is not changed and how to make this work?

I do not know if this is even possible to do this way. Maybe the `change` event is fired before the form is actually filled with `defaultValues`, so `event.target.value` keeps an old value, but it has no sense to me since Event object has correct value.

**UPDATE**: It works when dispatching is timed out.

```
form.addEventListener('reset', function (event) {
    console.log('Form reset!')
    setTimeout(() => {
        element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
    }, 1)
})
```

It seems like the event is dispatched before the reset event actually reset values to default, but I have no idea why `console.log(event)` shows Event with updated `event.target.value` when the "Reset" button is clicked.

Comment: In order to make it work before dispatch you could manually set the value to 0 `element.value = 0`. I'm sure its not the answer you want, but it does simply work.

Comment: not sure of what element.form is, and the following is pure speculation, but it may happen that your triggered "change" event occurs before the reset action itself. you can try to manually reset if (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) before triggering the change event.

Comment: @imvain2, Thanks, you gave me an idea. I ended up holding default value in variable when the document is loaded. Then, added inside `reset` listener `if` statement to check `element.value != defaultValue` since I have no reason to make an request if nothing has changed. Before dispatching `change` event, just added `element.value = defaultValue` and it works fine.